# Regex captures two elements, I only need one

Tags: regex

I have this kind of strings:

```
1M C 1 04 4,00 4,00 301 FERIE 4,00|

27L C 04 7,00 135,00 301 FERIE 1,00 |
```

and this regex:

```
\b\d{1,2}[LMGV|ISFD](\s|$)
```

This is working fine with the second string, but it captures also 00| (the end) of the second.

I need to capture 1M only.

Regexs already tried (mostly suggested by ChatGPT):

```
\b\d{1,2}([LMGV|ISFD])(\s|$)
\b\d{1,2}[LMGV|ISFD](?!\S)
\b\d{1,2}[LMGV|ISFD](?=\s|$)
\b\d{1,2}[LMGV|ISFD]
```

Please note that the strings come from an OCR that sometimes detects the L as a pipe, so including it in the list of allowed characters is not a typo, it is what I need.

Comment: Well, why is `|` in the class if you don’t want it?

Comment: You either make the `(\s|$)` a [non-capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), or you simply ignore it when using the result…?!

Comment: Try it like this `\b\d{1,2}[LMGVISFD]\b` https://regex101.com/r/a7TolN/1

Comment: @biffen because the strings are obtained from an OCR and unfortunately sometimes the first character, usually when it si an L, it is detected as a |, so I need to include it in the list.

Comment: `[LMGV|ISFD]` is most likely not what you want because it allows `|` as well literally.

Comment: I don’t understand why this question was closed. The motivation is that there is a typo, but I think that is people seeing the pipe and not reading that I’m using the OCR so I need that in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe is in the character class so that can also be matched after matching 2 digits.

If you don't want to match the pipe:

```
\b\d{1,2}[LMGVISFD]\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a7TolN/1)

If you do want to match the pipe because an `L` can be seen as `|` in OCR, you would need a rule in the regex that would allow to match it.

If the pipe is allowed to match only when the pattern is at the start of the string:

```
^\d{1,2}[LMGVISFD|]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/34v9ba/1)

Or if for example the pipe is not allowed at the end of the string, you can use a negative lookahead:

```
\b\d{1,2}[LMGVISFD|](?![^\S\n]*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D7jiX9/1)

Answer (score -1):

```
(\b\d{1,2}[LMGV|ISFD]).*|$
```

You can capture the group 1 from the above regex.

OR

Updated Regex:

```
^\d{1,2}[LMGV|ISFD]
```

Comment: Just explain why it was down voted? I just need a feedback. This was my first answer on stackoverflow.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I believe your issue is that `aaab|$` is very different to `aaa(b|$)` the first globally gives the alternative to match either `aaab` OR `$` which means JUST end of line. the latter alowes for `aaa$` or `aaab`, which in both cases includes `aaa`

Comment: I added an updated one now.